# Background Image not showing in iPhone/iPad but works fine in Mac/Windows/Andorid

Tags: css, iphone, background-image

I am using this CSS.

And it works fine in Mac/Windows/Android.

But not working on iPhone (lastest/old) or iPad.

```
label-certified {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(../img/Oakley_CRP_Sticker.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: Hi! why you are using display none?

Comment: it's not using that was overridden by other css.

updated my question

Comment: Could you please share link or more details we have to check the upper div/section styles

Comment: https://sg.oakley.com/en/store-finder here's the link

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
.finder .results .scroll-pane .result__item .info .label-container {
    left: 100%!important;
}
.finder .results .scroll-pane .result__item .info .label-container .label-certified {
    display: block !important;
    right: 0!important;
}
}
```

Comment: Not working. I have added your code but still not loading in iPhone